# Single File Upload issue with blueimp file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am facing a strange issue with blueimp jquery file upload.

In my form, I have multiple file input fields. Each input field has to accept only a single file.

What I have done first, is to remove the multiple option of the file input. My inputs now look like:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile-photo" id="userfile-photo" data-field="photo" />
```

Then i have disabled drag and drop by setting the following option:

```
dropZone: null,
```

The form upload is triggered by clicking a button.

The problem I am experiencing now is this that: 
I select a single file using this file input field, then I repeat the same action of selecting files four or five times using the same input field. During submit, all the files that I had been selecting using the same input field start uploading.

I expected the behaviour here would be, on input change, the previous input is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

To enforce a one file upload limit, you can make use of the maxNumberOfFiles option. set this option to 1 in your case.

you also need to remove the multiple attribute from your input field which you have done this part already.

> maxNumberOfFiles
>
> This option limits the number of files that are allowed to be uploaded
>   using this widget. By default, unlimited file uploads are allowed.
>
> Type: integer
>
> Example: 10
>
> Note: The maxNumberOfFiles option depends on
>   the getNumberOfFiles option, which is defined by the UI and AngularJS
>   implementations.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But the option did not work! It behaves the same even after adding the maxNumberOfFiles: 1,

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a combination of

```
sequentialUploads: true,
limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
maxNumberOfFiles: 1
```

Options.

You can also listen for the file added callback and disable the input yourself.  These callbacks are listed in documentation.  Added event is 'fileuploadadd' used like this in angular:

```
        $scope.$on('fileuploadadd', function(e, data){
            //file added, stop any more uploads
        });
```